# Blocking non ajax requests to API. Django. DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a decorator which allows only ajax requests to endpoints.

```
AJAX_ONLY = os.getenv('AJAX_ONLY', 'False') == 'True'

def only_ajax():

    def wrapper(func):

        def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):

            if not request.is_ajax() and AJAX_ONLY:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()

            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        return decorator

    return wrapper
```

Then I use it as a method_decorator in controllers:

```
@method_decorator(only_ajax(), name='dispatch')
class SomeEndpoint(APIView):
    ...
```

And it works perfectly good on localhost returning 403. But on the live servers it simply suggests user to log in displaying default DRF browsable api page afterwards.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: [is_ajax() detection method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) is based on a single header value `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. Are you sure that the live server use it ?

Comment: @Romain the code is completely identical on all servers.